# What is the most efficient way to reverse a char array?

Tags: java

I tried two different ways to reverse a `char` array

```
    //method 1
    char c[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    char c_rev[] = new char[4];
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        c_rev[i] = c[3 - i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c_rev));
```

---

```
    //method 2
    char c[]  = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        st.push(c[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c[i] = st.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

I just wondered **what will be the most efficient one**. Method 1 or Method 2 ?
Can anyone help me or give any suggestions ?

Comment: In terms of time complexity, they're both O(n).

Comment: @MarounMaroun : yes that is true. So if you need to choose a method ? What will you choose ?

Comment: None, use a ready method.

Comment: @MarounMaroun : can you explain that a little bit. I'm not familiar with that method ?

Comment: @prime.  Did any of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. As I'm sure you know by now this indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of time complexity, they're both O(n). Performance wouldn't be significant here.

Which to choose? None. I would use a ready method [`StringBuilder#reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--):

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(new String(c)).reverse().toString();
```

If I wanted to choose one from the two methods you posed, I would have choose the first one, it have only one loop and it's straightforward, no methods will be called, no helper objects will be created; you simply create a new array and directly push to it the new elements.

Comment: I have seen this method as well. So given that this would be a better approach if you are to select one of the given 2 methods (in the question) what will you choose. Just for learning purpose. In terms of time complexity, they're both O(n). Is there any way some method out perform the other ?

Comment: @prime I would have choose the first one, it have only one loop and it's straightforward.

Comment: That is the first thing which came to my  mind as well. Lets see what others have to say.

Answer (score 3):

@MarounMaroun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010301/1945631) will work for char arrays that are really strings. If you are worried only about those two methods then the first involves less heap allocations and GC.

However in general for an array I would use neither of your methods, but instead:

```
int len = c.length; 
for(int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    char ch = c[i];
    c[i] = c[len - i - 1];
    c[len - i - 1] = ch;
}
```

It is:

1. shorter to type than method 2
2. only iterates for half the array length (it is still O(n) due to the ops per iteration)
3. will work for any array type
4. doesn't need extra object allocations (vs Method 2) or two arrays (vs Method 1)

I would, however, be careful of micro-optimizations like this. The difference between this and Method 1 is probably minimal for small array allocations so you are better off using the one that is easiest for you to understand. (Similarly I only pulled the `len` variable out for clarity - some microbenchmarks claim it speeds up loops, but the downside is it pollutes your local variables with something that is only used inside the loop).

Comment: will this reverse the given array c ??

Comment: Good answer, note however that in terms of "big O" there's no difference between O(n/2) and O(n) - Both are linear according to n.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that method 1 is probably faster since it doesn't require the creation, allocation, and destruction of new objects (i.e. the Stack and its internal objects). For the same reason it should also have a lower impact on the garbage collector.

If this is a frequent operation in your code, you can benchmark both methods using something like [Google caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/). Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators works more efficiently than using a method of assignment operators (swapping) using third variable:

```
 public static char[] reverseArray(char[] array) {
    for(int i=0; i<array.length/2; i++)
    {
        array[i]^=array[array.length-i-1];
        array[array.length-i-1]^=array[i];
        array[i]^=array[array.length-i-1];
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = {'H','e','l','l','o'};
    System.out.println(reverseArray(input));
    char[] input2 = {'J','a','v','a'};
    System.out.println(reverseArray(input2));
}
```